# Sequence with $x_{n+2}=x_{n+1}x_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(x_n) _{n \ge 0} $ be a sequence so that $x_{n+2}=x_{n+1}x_n$,$x_0=a, x_1=b$, $a, b \in \mathbb{R} $. Study the monotony and the convergence of $(x_n) _n\ge 0$.
I think that I need to study the monotony and the convergence depending on the values of $a$ and $b$. What I have observed is that if $a, b>0$, then I can apply $\ln$ over the recurrence relation and find an explicit formula for $x_n$. If either of them is $0$,then $x_n=0,\forall n\in \mathbb{N} $. I am left with the cases when they are both negative and when one of them is negative and the other one is positive. I don't know what to do to solve them.

Comment: The solution for $a, b > 0$ will  have the form $x_n = a^{F_{n-1}} b^{F_n}$ where $F_n$ is some well known sequence. The same expression works even when $a, b$ are negative numbers (or any complex numbers)

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Where do you see that $a,b \geq 0$ ? I think that there is a misprint in the OP's question : it is not $(x_n)_n \geq 0$ but $(x_n)_{n \geq 0}$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe: I think you are right. Someone should edit this.

Comment: Yep, it really is a misprint, a Latex mistake.

Comment: The word is "monotonicity".

Comment: Yes, @TonyK, that is the word, but when I was teaching I would sometimes call functions monotonous if they exhibited that property.

Comment: @Lubin: I can't tell whether you are serious or not! For anybody with any doubts, a function is monotonic and a lecture is monotonous. "The monotonicity of the function was proven at length in a lecture of surpassing monotony."

Comment: @TonyK, I told no lie.

Answer (score 2):

Study $y_n = \ln |x_n|$, and look at the sign separately from the value.

Answer (score 0):

> What I have observed is that if a,b>0, then I can apply ln over the recurrence relation and find an explicit formula for xn.

If that is so (I do not know if you are correct) you are done. You have a formula for the absolute value of the terms and if one or both of $a,b$ is negative and neither is zero the signs will alternate. is a neg,neg, pos, neg, neg, pos..... pattern.  So you have a formula for all.

So if one of $a,b = 0$ then $x_i = 0$ for all $i\ge 2$.

Otherwise if $a,b > 0$ you have a formula $x_i = f(i)> 0$

Otherwise you have $x_0 = a; x_1 = b; x_2 =ab$ and of those two are negative and one is positive; $x_i = (-1)^m f(i)$ where $m$ is even if and only if $i \equiv \text{(index of first positive term)} \pmod 3$.